# PHP HTML Table is not sorting numerically when cells are hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

So I have a HTML table inside my PHP page (filled from MySQL database) and a specific column that I want to sort it numerically on click on the column header.
Alphabetically, the sort function is working with no problem.
Numerically, the sort function works only when I put data with no hyperlinks.
Here are the table (with and without hyperlink):

```
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <th onclick="sortTableId()">ID</th>
                        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Titre</th>
                        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Date de création</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <th onclick="sortTableId()">ID</th>
                        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Titre</th>
                        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Date de création</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href=petition-admin.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]?>'><?php echo $row[0]; ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And the JavaScript sort function :

```
function sortTableId() {
var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, a, b, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
switching = true;
dir = "asc";
while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
        if (dir == "asc") {
            if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
              }
        }
        else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
              }
        }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        switchcount++;
    } else {
        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}
A screenshot of the table :
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YLzQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `innerHTML` which will include the inner HTML markup so numeric conversion will be ... interesting.

Use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

Eg:

```
if (Number(x.innerText) > Number(y.innerText))
```

If you wanted to get really fancy you could add a `data-sortdata` data attribute and perhaps a `data-sortdatatype` attribute to handle things like currency ($4,000.00) boolean or images in cells (think check marks for bools etc) and perform your sort on these instead of markup in cells